# Exception Error: Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

Tags: error, ce-1.8.1.0

Tried to install magento 1.8.1 to my hosting server. Everything look fine in the frontend, and I can login to backend and add category. However when I try to modify it(e.g: Catalog>Manage Products)in the backend its getting exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Did I make anything wrong during the installation? Don't know how to fix it!
Thank you very much!

a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually";i:1;s:4121:"#0 /home/greenlight/www/www/ftp/magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php(197): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Create a new directory called `tmp`

Navigate to app/code/core/Zend/Cache/Backend/

Edit File.php

Change:

```
  protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'null',
```

to

```
  protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

Comment: Only find Db and XmlRpc folder under app/code/core/Zend/

Comment: Have a look at `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend`

Comment: I encountered this issue on a working environment, after only replicate a db dump. Do you have a hint?

Answer (score 0):

There's a well explained tutorial in the link above. Please take a look

http://mariosam.com.br/magento/erro-cache-dir/

Translated to english:
https://translate.google.com.br/translate?sl=pt&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmariosam.com.br%2Fmagento%2Ferro-cache-dir%2F&edit-text=&act=url