# Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

Tags: magento2, configuration, cache, products, magento-community

I have installed Magento 2.0.0.0 on Windows with IIS 8. When I try to add a new product I get a message:

"Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually"

[image: Error message on Products page]

When I click the 'Add Product' button anyway I don't get a data entry form that I would expect - it's mostly blank.

[image: Blank new product screen]

I have looked around at solutions, but they all seem to focus on versions earlier than 2.0.0.0 (e.g. [this one applies to 1.8.1.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16368/exception-error-could-not-determine-temp-directory-please-specify-a-cache-dir)) and this is important because there is no app/code/core/Zend/Cache/Backend/ folder as described in that solution. There is however:

lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend and a File.php there. I have changed line 42 here to:

```
    'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp/',
```

(Even though hacking away at the file in 'lib' doesn't feel right).

Still the message and problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

This error is not Magento-specific. It relates to Zend Cache.

Set `sys_temp_dir` in `php.ini` to a path that can be reached by IUSR then restart IIS to apply changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve the issue, but it is possible to specify custom directories for cache (and other directories declared in `\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::getDefaultConfig`) during Magento installation using command line argument: `--magento-init-params=MAGE_DIRS[cache][path]=/var/tmp/magento/var/cache&MAGE_DIRS[tmp][path]=/var/tmp/magento/var/tmp`

Also, `MAGE_DIRS` should be initialized using `SetEnv` in web server config (e.g. in virtual host config), so that custom directories are used during each request processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you got no rights to edit the `php.ini`, you can set up a PHP mod-version. Now use the following in your `.htaccess`

```
SetEnv TEMP /www/htdocs/your/path/mage/var/tmp
SetEnv TMP /www/htdocs/your/path/mage/var/tmp
SetEnv TMPDIR /www/htdocs/your/path/mage/var/tmp
```

You will need that for web hosters that support this.